# Show only 3rd Level Wordpress menu

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm working on this site here: http://new.leicesterymca.co.uk/youth-community/our-work/

On this page you will see I have the 1st level menu at the top, then I have PHP code saying if there is a 2nd level menu then display the 2nd level menu in the blue strip.

But now I need the same for the 3rd level menu (on the left of the page). So Essentially I need the code to see if there are any 3rd level pages, if so then display the 3rd level pages here. The code I have for the second level is:

```
<?php
  $menu = wp_nav_menu(
      array (
        'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
        'sub_menu' => true,
        'echo' => FALSE,
        'fallback_cb' => '__return_false'
      )
  );
  if ( ! empty ( $menu ) )
  {
    echo '<div class="sub-nav-container-full">
          <div class="container">
          <div class="sub-page-menu">';
    echo $menu;
    echo '</div></div></div>';
  }
?>
```

So, I'm assuming I can use similar code but I don't know how to aim it at the 3rd level only?

If anyone could help, that would be great! :)

Thanks, Shaun.

EXTRA - I also have this bit of code in my functions file if it helps...

```
// FUNCTION FOR SETTING UP SUB MENU PAGES

// add hook
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'my_wp_nav_menu_objects_sub_menu', 10, 2 );

// filter_hook function to react on sub_menu flag
function my_wp_nav_menu_objects_sub_menu( $sorted_menu_items, $args ) {
  if ( isset( $args->sub_menu ) ) {
    $root_id = 0;

// find the current menu item
foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $menu_item ) {
  if ( $menu_item->current ) {
    // set the root id based on whether the current menu item has a parent or not
    $root_id = ( $menu_item->menu_item_parent ) ? $menu_item->menu_item_parent : $menu_item->ID;
    break;
  }
}

// find the top level parent
if ( ! isset( $args->direct_parent ) ) {
  $prev_root_id = $root_id;
  while ( $prev_root_id != 0 ) {
    foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $menu_item ) {
      if ( $menu_item->ID == $prev_root_id ) {
        $prev_root_id = $menu_item->menu_item_parent;
        // don't set the root_id to 0 if we've reached the top of the menu
        if ( $prev_root_id != 0 ) $root_id = $menu_item->menu_item_parent;
        break;
      } 
    }
  }
}

$menu_item_parents = array();
foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $key => $item ) {
  // init menu_item_parents
  if ( $item->ID == $root_id ) $menu_item_parents[] = $item->ID;

  if ( in_array( $item->menu_item_parent, $menu_item_parents ) ) {
    // part of sub-tree: keep!
    $menu_item_parents[] = $item->ID;
  } else if ( ! ( isset( $args->show_parent ) && in_array( $item->ID, $menu_item_parents ) ) ) {
    // not part of sub-tree: away with it!
    unset( $sorted_menu_items[$key] );
  }
}

return $sorted_menu_items;
  } else {
return $sorted_menu_items;
  }
}
```

Comment: In other words, you want to show the 3rd level menu when the 2nd level is shown / hovered?

Comment: I think so - I want the 3rd level menu to who in that position (left side of page) when there is one and when you have clicked on the parent 2nd level menu.... Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your question is similar to this one and I think you can get this to work for you as well !

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45161/3-level-deep-navigation-menu-not-showing-all-levels

Comment: I don't think this is the same thing - My menu is showing all levels correctly on hover, but I just want it to show the 3rd level of sub menus only. This shows me how to enable all levels to display, in particular when using the Roots Theme...